# What is the best way for a VFR pilot to get a class B clearance when entering the DC SFRA?

Tags: class-b-airspace, special-use-airspace

When flying into BWI I need to enter class B airspace but also the Washington DC SFRA.

Assuming I have filed my flight plan to enter the SFRA correctly before my flight, how do I manage the radio calls in flight?

From my understanding:

- I need to call the gate (e.g PALEO 132.775) to activate my flight plan and enter the SFRA, however they cannot clear me into the class B.
- I need to speak to Potomac Approach (e.g. 119.0) to enter the class B.

Do I get clearance into the SFRA from PALEO first, telling them I'm going to BWI? Then, once I have clearance and a squawk code do I switch to BWI to get clearance into class B?

[image: Cross sectional of BWI/Washington SFRA]

Any example radio calls would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this not covered in the online SFRA training? (It may not be; genuine question.)

Comment: Nope. The example they give is flying to Manasses, which I think they use as they can fly under the class B shelf. They just say to tell ATC when you have the airport in sight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to cover all bases, if you have an instrument rating the simplest way is to file and fly an ordinary every day IFR flight. There will be no special clearances or requests.

For VFR folks. The rule is to be in contact with ATC while in the SFRA, but it does not need to be the VFR gate. The gate frequency is mainly to keep VFR chatter from cluttering IFR frequencies, the Gate and Potomac approach controllers are all in the same room and may even be the same person depending on how they divided sectors that day.

Class B is positively controlled airspace so there is no self navigation. You will not only get a clearance to enter, you will stay on their frequency (until they hand you off to tower or another sector) and follow navigation instructions the entire time you are in bravo.

Contact PALEO gate to activate the SFRA flight plan as normal, several miles from either SFRA or class Bravo. If it isn't clear from their communications make sure PALEO knows you are landing BWI and need to enter class bravo.

PALEO should then just hand you off to the approach frequency. Switch to that frequency, "Potomac approach, N1234 with you", wait for response and answer questions[eg state request, aircraft type, ident, etc.], request to enter bravo for landing at BWI visual approach, (If they didn't beat you to it), follow vectors and altitudes reading them back.

But make sure you hear an explicit "cleared into class bravo" before entering bravo. Ask if you are not sure that you heard it even if they gave you vectors.